# How to check not mapped columns in schema using Hibernate 4.2.21.Final

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, maven, junit

I have mapping for entities against Oracle DB tables. Would like to check in integration test whether we have any columns in tables for which mapping are absent. 
For deleted and changed columns there is exception during initiation of persistence context, for added columns there is no any alerts.

Comment: I don't think thats possible. that is because there is no need to always map all columns. That is the case there is no error for unmapped columns. But for wrongly mapped columns you get an error, because hibernate can't store or fetch data from non existing/wrongly mapped columns

Comment: I believe the neatest solution is Hibernate Integrator API, but it requires Hibernate 5